# Embedded linux remote update

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, software-updates, yocto

I build my own linux distribution using Yocto for Rpi CM4. I would like to have a possibility to update it remotely, without using Balena Etcher, just upload the built image  and call some commands via SSH.

How can I do that? I found swupdate yocto layer but I cannot confirm that it will work with CM4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used RAUC. It has support for RPI CM4/4B.

Just add those layers to yocto:

```
https://github.com/rauc/meta-rauc
https://github.com/rauc/meta-rauc-community/tree/master/meta-rauc-raspberrypi
```

Then follow the instruction from `readme.md` from the second URL.

Works without any struggle.